# Integrating email clients in one website using C#.Net / ASP.Net

Tags: email, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

The problem is -

" I have to design one website, which will contain number of blocks. Each block will refer to different email client. That means, a user of this site can see his/her all mail clients in one one blocks."

The user will provide his/her existing mail clients information (Username and Password) at the time of registering into this site.

So, when user comes to the site he will login by providing username and password of this site (and not with user name or password of any of his mail clients) and he will see his home page containing all his existing mail clients opened directly in one one block (without logging in to any of the mail client).

Basically, this website will help the user to use all mail clients in one page.

Will anybody suggest how to do this task ?

It will be better if working codes will be provided.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds quite difficult - you will need to make a good web mail client, and it is very hard to compete with the existing services in this area. For instance, it would be hard to make a webmail client as good as the one gmail has.

If you can make a good webmail client, the rest is quite easy - the user would give login details for POP/IMAP services for each of their email services, and then you could make your server log in to each of them and pull back any mail to display.

It may be easier for you to purchase existing webmail client software, and then wire it up to a database containing user login details to make the website you require.

Comment: please help me doing what u said. I think u r saying to create another mail client. But that is not the answer. The Question is to build one website or web application, through which user can access all his mail clients in one page...

Answer (score 0):

I've used this component in the past and may help with sending and reading emails/attachement from a variety of sources.

[Rebex.net](http://www.rebex.net/mail.net/)

Comment: I saw and implemented what u said. But this is not the answer I wanted. Actually, I want to open all the mail clients exact home pages directly with one login.That means, the user can access gmail in one block, rediffmail in another and like that...

Comment: You could try hosting the email clients in individual iframes, though i dont know how you would log them in automatically

Comment: I was also have this idea. But, how can I then log in automatically ??; that is what my question is all about. Any way, Thanks. If u find any solution, then reply me. Bye...